# Firing Keyboard event on focusing QlineEdit?

Tags: qt, keyboard-events, onfocus, qlineedit

Is there any way for firing external keyboard event after focusing on a specific QlineEdit.
Actually, I am developing a multi language application in qt in which I want google tools to be turned off & on based on the line edit on which it is focused.

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Override the [focusInEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusInEvent) and emit a signal of your choice

```
void my_lineedit::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* event)
{
    emit my_signal();
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Better call `QLineEdit::focusInEvent(event);` instead.

Comment: How to emit a signal Ctrl+G

Comment: I haven't tried this but [here is an approach](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/622)

Comment: I have to generate my own signal(i.e. Ctrl+G) based on which line edit has been in focus.

Comment: So where is the problem? You need to clearly identify which lineedit is selected? Define an enum containing the identifiers, give the lineedit class a member of that enum and set it in your code. Then in the focusInEvent, fire a signal dependant on the enum value set

Answer (score 0):

I am able to check that whether line edit is in focus but i am not able to fire the 'Ctrl+G' event after focusing.
Below is my code snippet,

```
bool DemoDialog::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == ui->leAge)
    {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Inside Event";
        QKeyEvent *evnent=new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::CTRL+Qt::Key_G,Qt::NoModifier,QString(""));
        QApplication::sendEvent(this,evnent);
    }
}
return QObject::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```